# When removing a class with jQuery, is it better to include the class in the selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Probably this will not result in any noticable performance difference, but I was just interested. If I am removing a class on a list of elements using jQuery, is it better practice or performance to include the class in the selector?

So either include it:

```
$('#myList li.classToRemove').removeClass('classToRemove');
```

or don't include it:

```
$('#myList li').removeClass('classToRemove');
```

So basically is there any difference to narrowing the list in the selector and in the removeClass method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selectors are matched backwards (last to first), meaning it will first find "all elements with "classToRemove" which are also "li" which are also children of "#mylist" ".

It's done that way to narrow down the list as much as possible, as soon as possible.

Therefore, you should go with

```
$('#myList li.classToRemove').removeClass('classToRemove');
```

Less items to match means a faster, more efficient script.

Comment: I don't think it'll improve anything, It's just another check that JQuery will have to do. redundant.

Comment: Wrong, instead of checking for every li, it will first search every `.classToRemove`, which will narrow down the list further. See the following article: http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

Comment: I misunderstood the question. You're right, I thought he's asking something else. **+1**

Comment: `li.classToRemove` may or may not necessarily mean finding `.classToRemove` first, depending on implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that not all the `<li>` elements have that class, then I'd say that it's better to run `.removeClass()` on the filtered set.

But overall, there will be other things that will have an impact on the performance, like...

- The number of elements matched by `'#myList li'` vs `'#myList li.classToRemove'`
- The way different environments optimize their DOM selection
- The actual performance difference of the innards of the `.removeClass()` method between different environments

So unless you're talking about unnecessarily running `.removeClass()` on a large subset of elements, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: +1 for "large subset of elements".  Hitting an `li` with `.removeClass('classToRemove')` that doesn't have that class is going to be a tiny, tiny hit.  Unless you have millions of `li`s :P

Answer (score 0):

Using the more specific selector will improve performance but it won't affect the result of .removeClass().

Think of each addition to a selector like a drill down. Given the html below:

```
    <div id="myList">
        <ul>
            <li id="li1"></li>
            <li id="li2"></li>
            <li id="li3" class="classToRemove"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    //In order of fastest to slowest:
    //Selecting the exact li and calling removeClass once
    $('#li3').removeClass('classToRemove');

    //In this one we are skipping 2 li's and then calling removeClass once
    $('#myList li.classToRemove').removeClass('classToRemove');

    //In this one we have to call removeClass 3 times
    $('#myList li').removeClass('classToRemove');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump an old post.

The test at [this page](http://jsperf.com/jquery-remove-class-selector/3) seems to suggest that NOT including the class selector is around 10-15% quicker. So, if you want to use jQuery, the best approach is just:

```
$('#myList li').removeClass('classToRemove');
```

- Note - this page does appear to use jQuery 1...